# ImportError: No module named 'encodings' on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, python

My Ubuntu 16.04 has broken packages and unmet dependencies. I tried to fix the system as suggested by using:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Once I do that. I get these packages will be installed:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bridge-utils dh-python gir1.2-glib-2.0 libgirepository-1.0-1 libpython-all-dev libpython-dev libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev pigz python-all python-apt-common python2.7-dev
  python3 python3-minimal python3.5 python3.5-minimal ubuntu-fan
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

Once I proceed with installation, I am getting the following error:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LC_TERMINAL_VERSION = "3.3.9",
    LC_TERMINAL = "iTerm2",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up python3.5-minimal (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.9) ...
# Empty sitecustomize.py to avoid a dangling symlink
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f5fe3a58700 (most recent call first):
Aborted
dpkg: error processing package python3.5-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 134
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-minimal:
 python3-minimal depends on python3.5-minimal (>= 3.5.1-2~); however:
  Package python3.5-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.5-minimal
 python3-minimalE: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried the solution suggested as setting `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH`

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/
export PYTHONHOME=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/
```

But this didn't worked. Then I tried also by unsetting those env variable, but it also had same effect.

Since, this is a shared host. I checked following:

```
$which python
$which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
$which python2
/usr/bin/python2
$ python -V
Python 3.6.4
```

Is there something need to be clean and reset the system ? Or completely uninstall python, but I read somewhere, it may lead system unusable.

My Ubuntu version:

```
$cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
```